# Bash: better way to output to both console and output file than tee?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, bash-scripting

What I need to display is a log refreshing periodically. It's a block of about 10 lines of text. I'm using |tee and it works right now. However, the performance is less satisfying. It waits a while and then outputs several blocks of texts from multiple refreshes (especially when the program just starts, it takes quite a while to start displaying anything on the console and the first time I saw this, I thought the program was hanging). In addition, it breaks randomly in the middle of the last block, so it's quite ugly to present.

Is there a way to improve this? (Maybe output less each time and switch between output file and console more frequently?)

**Update**: Here is what's in my bash script right now: 
`tail -f /var/log/syslog | egrep --line-buffered "my search string" > tmp.txt & python script.py | tee result.log`

Comment: Is it a self-written program?  If so you can try to flush the output buffer every block or lines of text.  By default the output buffer is only actually written when the buffer is full (or periodically?  I'm not sure).

Answer (score 5):

I think your problem arises from a fundamental feature of pipes i.e. buffering.

The workarounds are messy but you should look at commands like `unbuffer` or `script` or `stdbuf`.

Perhaps something to stop output bufferring by tee like this:

```
 your_program | stdbuf -o0 tee
```

PS. I'm not at a console now so I cannot try this.

Comment: I think it should be `stdbuf -o0 your_program | stdbuf -i0 -o0 tee` to completely get rid of buffering

Comment: `script` works.

Answer (score 1):

I use a command grouping and redirect the ouput into a process substitution. Inside, I echo it to /dev/tty and to stdout. Then I redirect stdout and stderr to a file. Works for me so far. You can easily prepend the output with timestamp and a process identifier if you want.

```
{
  #script goes here
} > >(while read TEXT ; do MESSAGE="$(date +"%d.%m.%Y") $(date +"%Hh%Mm%Ss") $LOGPREFIX $TEXT"; echo $MESSAGE; echo $MESSAGE > /dev/tty; done >> $LOGFILE) 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [`script`](https://www.tecmint.com/record-and-replay-linux-terminal-session-commands-using-script/)

Run

```bsh
$ script -c "your_program" result.log
```

instead of

```bsh
$ your_program | tee result.log
```

e.g. `script -c "ls" result.log`.

BTW: With `script` you can record whole bash session, which you start with
`script result.log`
and end with
`exit` command.

This answer is already included by @curious_cat and is same answer to this question: [Recording a bash session](https://superuser.com/questions/1050627/recording-a-bash-session)