# Recording a bash session

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, logging

For auditing and documentation purposes, I'd like to find a command such that everything that happens in a given bash session, is written to a file.

I.e., I'd like to end up with a file that shows all the command I ran, and all the outputs of these commands.

I know I can get part of that using the history file (commands run), and part of that by redirecting output.

However, I feel like bash should have this capability by itself, and I just have not found it.

Example:

```
> bash --some-kind-of-magic output.txt
$ cat file1.txt
this is the content of file1.txt
$ grep test file2.txt
this is the output of the command
$ exit
> cat output.txt
$ cat file1.txt
this is the content of file1.txt
$ grep test file2.txt
this is the output of the command
$ exit
```

Comment: Oh gosh, you're right. Thank you! That works perfectly for me. I'll accept your answer once the cooldown is up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `script` to log all outputs from a command, or even to start a command. One command which you could start is a new issue of a shell. E.g. 
`script my_log /usr/local/bin/bash`

If this is not a once off then please mention that in your post. (In which case you probably want to set it in the login scripts for that user, possibly exec script and placing the log somwhere where the log cannot be manipulated).