# Write the list of content of a .rar or zip archive into a txt log file with 7z

Tags: linux, command-line, 7-zip, raspbian, tee

I have a huge archive.rar and I would like to know its content without extracting it.
Using 7z on a Raspbian

Here are the commands i tried that did just write an empty output.txt file :

```
sudo 7z l archive.rar > output.txt
7z l archive.rar | sudo tee output.txt
7z l -so archive.rar | sudo tee -a output.txt
```

I hope someone will be able to help me :)

Thank you a lot in advance

Comment: Why are you sprinkling `sudo` in all the commands? It's not required.

Comment: because i get the message : -bash permission denied to write ouput.txt if i don't

Comment: Do the commands exit by themselves? or do you Ctrl+c each one because "nothing happens"?

Comment: Does `7z l archive.rar` alone show the contents? Why are you writing to a folder where you don't have permissions?

Comment: If I use 7z l archive.rar ->the output start to appear on the screen directly, if i add tee -> "nothing happens" but isn't tee supposed to show the output on screen AND write it in output.txt ?

Comment: The folder is on an external drive, if i log as root the result is the same, if i use "7z l archive.rar" i start to get the output but the process is really really long, if i wait a very very long time with tee, nothing shows, nothing happens, output.txt stays empty thank you

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42938106/10765659) is [how](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/108618) things [work](https://superuser.com/q/889019/432690). The easiest solution is: be patient.